# Pure CSS3 constantly moving slider

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to make constantly moving slider with only CSS3 (and later Sass).
I have nine images and mask div with 850px width and I know how to animate first image, but how to calculate values for rest of them.

I find nice tutorials on [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/) and [hugogiraudel.com](http://hugogiraudel.com/2014/07/16/automating-css-animations-with-sass/), but there is static state, and I don't know how to make it still moving.

It would be great if some one can help me to understand this and how use SASS for this.

Here is [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQzwWP) with what I done.
And here is code:

```css
#slider {
  width: 850px;
  margin: 0 150px;
}
.ruler {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.u10 {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
}
.u10:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
.u10:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: gray;
}
ul {
  list-style: outside none none;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}
ul:after {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
}
li {
  position: absolute;
}
.img1 {
  left: -120px;
}
.img2 {
  left: 0px;
}
.img3 {
  left: 120px;
}
.img4 {
  left: 240px;
}
.img5 {
  left: 360px;
}
.img6 {
  left: 480px;
}
.img7 {
  left: 600px;
}
.img8 {
  left: 720px;
}
.img9 {
  left: 840px;
}
.animation {
  animation: 10s linear 0s infinite running cycle1;
}
@keyframes cycle1 {
  0% {
    left: -120px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    left: -120px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    left: 840px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    left: -120px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div class="ruler">
    <span class="u10">10%</span>
    <span class="u10">20%</span>
    <span class="u10">30%</span>
    <span class="u10">40%</span>
    <span class="u10">50%</span>
    <span class="u10">60%</span>
    <span class="u10">70%</span>
    <span class="u10">80%</span>
    <span class="u10">90%</span>
    <span class="u10">100%</span>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class="image-wrapper img1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=1" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=2" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=3" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=4" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img5">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=5" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=6" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img7">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=7" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img8">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=8" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img9">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=9" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="image-wrapper img1 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=1" alt="">
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How about wrapping all images and then animate that wrapper instead of just one image at a time?

Comment: @LuudJacobs: That's one option but animating the wrapper as opposed to individual elements would mean the animation should stay on till the last element has completely come into view and gone out. This would affect the *continuous nature* of the slider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For making a constantly moving slider animation, don't assign different positions to each of the image elements. Instead, position them at the same place outside the parent element and then give each of them a progressively different `animation-delay` like in the below snippet. Giving each image element a different starting position will mean each of them need to be provided a different duration because of the speed having to be different (as the amount of pixels it must cover from left to right would be high).

Since there are a total of 9 images within the container at any point of time, the delay for each of the individual image elements should be equal to `(animation-duration/9) * (n-1)` where `n` is the no. of the element. For simplicity sake, I had modified the `animation-duration` to 9s and so for the first image the `animation-delay` would be 0s and that for the second image would be 1s and so on.

```css
#slider {
  width: 850px;
  margin: 0 150px;
}
.ruler {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.u10 {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
}
.u10:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
.u10:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: gray;
}
ul {
  list-style: outside none none;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}
ul:after {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
}
li {
  position: absolute;
}
.img1 {
  left: -120px;
}
.img2 {
  left: 0px;
}
.img3 {
  left: 120px;
}
.img4 {
  left: 240px;
}
.img5 {
  left: 360px;
}
.img6 {
  left: 480px;
}
.img7 {
  left: 600px;
}
.img8 {
  left: 720px;
}
.img9 {
  left: 840px;
}
.animation {
  animation: 9s linear 0s infinite running cycle1;
}
@keyframes cycle1 {
  0% {
    left: -120px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    left: -120px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    left: 850px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    left: -120px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.animation[class*='img'] {
  left: -120px;
}
.animation.img2 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.animation.img3 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.animation.img4 {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
.animation.img5 {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
.animation.img6 {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
.animation.img7 {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.animation.img8 {
  animation-delay: 7s;
}
.animation.img9 {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}
ul.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <div class="ruler">
    <span class="u10">10%</span>
    <span class="u10">20%</span>
    <span class="u10">30%</span>
    <span class="u10">40%</span>
    <span class="u10">50%</span>
    <span class="u10">60%</span>
    <span class="u10">70%</span>
    <span class="u10">80%</span>
    <span class="u10">90%</span>
    <span class="u10">100%</span>
  </div>
  <h3>Without animation</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="image-wrapper img1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=1" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=2" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=3" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=4" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img5">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=5" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=6" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img7">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=7" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img8">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=8" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img9">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=9" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h3>With the portions outside the container visible</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="image-wrapper img1 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=1" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img2 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=2" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img3 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=3" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img4 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=4" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img5 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=5" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img6 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=6" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img7 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=7" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img8 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=8" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img9 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=9" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h3>With the portions outside the container hidden</h3>
  <ul class='overflow-hidden'>
    <li class="image-wrapper img1 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=1" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img2 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=2" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img3 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=3" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img4 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=4" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img5 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=5" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img6 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=6" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img7 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=7" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img8 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=8" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img9 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=9" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

If you want images to be visible in container at the beginning itself (as opposed to an empty container at start) then it is tough to achieve it without adding extra elements. You can use the same approach as mentioned above, add an extra dummy wrapper with all 9 images inside it and animate it only once such that it precedes the real animation. The below snippet has a sample for this approach.

```css
#slider {
  width: 850px;
  margin: 0 150px;
}
.ruler {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.u10 {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
}
.u10:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
.u10:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: gray;
}
ul {
  list-style: outside none none;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}
ul:after {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
}
li {
  position: absolute;
}
.img1 {
  left: -120px;
}
.img2 {
  left: 0px;
}
.img3 {
  left: 120px;
}
.img4 {
  left: 240px;
}
.img5 {
  left: 360px;
}
.img6 {
  left: 480px;
}
.img7 {
  left: 600px;
}
.img8 {
  left: 720px;
}
.img9 {
  left: 840px;
}
.animation {
  animation: 9s linear 5s infinite running cycle1; /* small delay added for image to be loaded, this can be ignored if image is preloaded */
}
@keyframes cycle1 {
  0% {
    left: -100px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  0.01% {
    left: -100px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.99% {
    left: 854px; /* total distance to be covered to be same as width of the dummy wrapper */
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.animation[class*='img'] {
  left: -100px;
}
.animation.img1 {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.animation.img2 {
  animation-delay: 7s;
}
.animation.img3 {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}
.animation.img4 {
  animation-delay: 9s;
}
.animation.img5 {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}
.animation.img6 {
  animation-delay: 11s;
}
.animation.img7 {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.animation.img8 {
  animation-delay: 13s;
}
ul.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-dummy {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  width: 954px; /* 100px image width + 6px imaee margin * no. of images */
  animation: 9s linear dummy-move 1 forwards 5s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0px;
}
.image-dummy img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
@keyframes dummy-move {
  from {
    left: -100px;
  }
  to {
    left: 866px; /* rough calculation equal to width of container * (margin-right * 2) */
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <div class="ruler">
    <span class="u10">10%</span>
    <span class="u10">20%</span>
    <span class="u10">30%</span>
    <span class="u10">40%</span>
    <span class="u10">50%</span>
    <span class="u10">60%</span>
    <span class="u10">70%</span>
    <span class="u10">80%</span>
    <span class="u10">90%</span>
    <span class="u10">100%</span>
  </div>
  <h3>Without animation</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="image-wrapper img1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=1" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=2" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=3" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=4" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img5">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=5" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=6" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img7">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=7" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img8">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=8" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img9">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=9" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h3>With the portions outside the container visible</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="image-wrapper img1 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=1" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img2 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=2" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img3 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=3" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img4 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=4" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img5 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=5" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img6 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=6" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img7 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=7" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img8 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=8" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img9 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=9" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h3>With the portions outside the container hidden</h3>
  <ul class='overflow-hidden'>
    <li class="image-wrapper img1 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=1" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img2 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=2" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img3 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=3" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img4 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=4" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img5 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=5" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img6 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=6" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img7 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=7" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img8 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=8" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="image-wrapper img9 animation">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=9" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class='image-dummy'>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=9" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=8" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=7" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=6" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=5" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=4" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=3" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=2" alt="">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=1" alt="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is more easier than adapting your approach to produce this effect because your approach would require 9 different keyframe settings to produce the effect that you require.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Harry but your solution have one problem, at the beginning container is empty (is not acceptable). Do you know how to make it with my approach (with different image positions) or maybe there is now solution on my problem in pure CSS?

Comment: With your approach it is extremely difficult to achieve (and maintain) continuous movement. I will try and see if my approach can be adapted.

Comment: @user19291: I have adapted my approach to produce the effect that you required. Please check if this helps and if it does, consider marking the answer as accepted.